# gmail api HttpError 403 when requesting "website" returned "Insufficient Permission"

Tags: python, gmail-api

i want to send an email through python by using gmail API,but

```
send_message(service , user_id = 'steve2020301@gmail.com', message = messages)
```

it comes out this

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "location Type": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

can somebody save me

---

additional code
[send_message function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwtOx.png)
[the parameter of send_message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iu9CY.png)
sorry i can't show the code by words because this page say my code is not format

Comment: I am not the best on python but know a little syntax around languages and I think you are passing your user_id and message parameters wrongly. I think it is function decleration syntax. Other than this, can you give us your api configuration. How it is your service and messages declerations?

Comment: hi , i have update the question with more information , thanks a lot

Comment: You're having a problem with the authentication of the service, have you authorized the token with the prompted consent screen? If so, you should have a token.pickle file in your project's directory. You can follow the [quickstart steps](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python). Let me know if this helps solve your problem!

Comment: sorry,but i already have the token.pickle file

Comment: Are you having a 403 error as stated in the question title or a 401 error as it's in the question? Have you followed the quickstart steps? If you have added new scopes you need to delete the token.pickle file and run the application again, so a new token.pickle file is created with the updated scopes.